# How to configure os.system() and subprocess lib?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to clone git repo from python using `os`:

```
  `os.system(repo_dir)`
```

Where `repo_dir` is a command + directory to github repository, like `git clone https://github.com/rudskoy/pyTelegramBotAPI`

One thing I try to investigate, where is a result of the command?

There are two scenarios I followed to investigate this:

1. Trying to gather output using `subprocess` from `git clone` command like that:

   `output = subprocess.check_output("git clone "https://github.com/rudskoy/pyTelegramBotAPI", shell=True)`

Then `output` = ' ' – I supposed this is ok, because if I try to repeat the command it throws an exception.

2. I tried to find the actual result using `mdfind` in terminal: `mdfind kind:folder "PyTelegramBotAPI"`

In the result: [image]

I suppose that subprocess call for output and os.system() work the same (they clones repos into /Documents/)

***My questions:***

About `subprocess` call — why my output is empty?

About `os.system()` – how to change the targeted directory (for instance, make it to write into ~/some_dir instead of ~/Users//Documents). I can specify the directory in command wrapped by os.system(), but I want to make it using os.system(), I think it's much correct.

Comment: Wait, what? "os.system(repo_dir) ... where repo_dir is ... https://github.com/rudskoy/pyTelegramBotAPI"? Are you trying to pass a URL to `os.system`? That's not how `os.system` works.

Comment: Ops, mistaken. Will correct now.

upd: i've corrected the question

Comment: Both `os.system` and `subprocess` run their commands in the current working directory, just like if you run the commands directly in the terminal.

Comment: Oh, damn. Thanks.